# Insecure stylesheet WordPress

Tags: wordpress, stylesheet

Im having problems with WordPress, I'm getting this error everywhere in the site, wp-admin, home dir and etc. I can't find a way to fix it because I cant see the valid URL of it. Error looks like this, I received it while trying to edit widget in widgets area wp-admin:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://somesite.com/wp-admin/widgets.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://somesite.com/?ver=1.11.4'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Maybe anyone had similar problem, please help!

Answer (score 1):

That error is generates by Google Chrome any time a website with SSL certificate (a website that uses HTTPS) try to call a URL without HTTPS, in your case you are calling somewhere in the code the URL "http://somesite.com/?ver=1.11.4" (probably in the menu or in the header).

There is a Wordpress plugin called "SSL Insecure Content Fixer" that can help you out in this problem, basically that plugin replace all the string "http://somesite.com/..." with "https://somesite.com/...".

So check it out, I think it will help you.

Comment: Tried "SSL Insecure Content Fixer" still the same.

Comment: can you locate where "http://somesite.com/?ver=1.11.4" is? probably it will be in header.php or menu.php.

Comment: Found problem, there was problems with redirection.

Comment: @Sidas Can you give us your exact solution? What exactly did you do?

Comment: Download the plugin SSL Insecure Content Fixer, it should work, otherwise you need to edit the header.php or footer.php and change http:// to https://

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with redirects. If anyone has similar problems. Try to look at your server and htaccess redirects. Otherwise this was not your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of the two things worked for me:

1. In Settings > General I updated "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" from using "http" to "https".
2. In Dashboard > Updates I updated all the installed themes.

I'm not sure which of these resolved the issue, but it seemed to work.